# The limitation of Arrays.asList() is not true in Thinking in Java 4th Edition

Tags: java, inheritance, type-inference

In this book, it says :

> A limitation of **Arrays.asList()** is that it takes a best guess about
>   the resulting type of the **List**, and doesn't pay attention to what you
>   are assigning it to.

The book is *Thinking in Java By Bruce Eckel*

However, the following code is working fine, contrary to code shown in this book page 280

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Snow> snow = Arrays.asList(new Light(), new Heavy());
    }
}
class Snow {}
class Powder extends Snow {}
class Light extends Powder {}
class Heavy extends Powder {}
```

Java 1.8 , IntelliJ, Windows 7
[image]

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Powder, Light, Heavy  class acquiring properties of Snow class then which obviously work fine

Comment: Two things:  first, you're getting back something that at least conforms to the `List` interface, so there's no problem there, and second, what would you have expected to be the problem?  Nothing here immediately jumps out that this is obviously massively wrong...

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: @KevinEsche Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: @Ajinkya Sorry, I updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code fails in Java-7, but compiles in Java-8. Using javac 7u80 I see:

```
Main.java:7: error: incompatible types
                List<Snow> snow = Arrays.asList(new Light(), new Heavy());
                                               ^
  required: List<Snow>
  found:    List<Powder>
1 error
```

The type inference in Java-8 was significantly improved. Prior to that the type was inferred for every sub-expression exclusively based on the analysis of that sub-expression, so the type of `Arrays.asList(new Light(), new Heavy())` was required to be known regardless of the surrounding context. In Java-8 the surrounding context may account to the expression type.

In Java Language Specification version 8 there's a [whole new chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) dedicated to the type inference. It's not very easy to read, but to my understanding now instead of assigning the concrete type to every subexpression a set of [constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.2) is assigned. In our case the constraints are `Light <: T && Heavy <: T` (no exact type is inferred here). Next the reduction process is performed which reduces the set of constraints to the set of bounds taking into account [expression compatibility constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.1).

Comment: appriciate but would you please explain a little deeper about surronding context and expression type.??

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I added some explanations, but to understand this in full detail you have to read the specification.